# PhpStorm - remove empty lines from end of file

Tags: phpstorm, removing-whitespace

At the moment I'm testing PhpStorm IDE. It is really great, except one feature. It doesn't remove empty lines from end of file. It's now remove unneeded whitespaces, but empty lines at the end aren't removed.

It's really annoying for me. Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please vote for [IDEA-119281](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119281)